# scrubbing through images is slow with PyQT5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

So I'm trying to develop an app that has a slider with which I am able to scroll through images.

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QHBoxLayout, QSlider, QLabel
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QImage
from utils import read_screenshots
import time

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = "offline viz"
        self.top = 200
        self.left = 500
        self.width = 1400
        self.height = 1300
        self.InitWindow()

    
    def InitWindow(self):
        hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        min, max, self.screenshots = read_screenshots()

        self.slider_text = QLabel(self)
        self.slider_text.setGeometry(100, 830, 900, 20)

        self.ScreenShot = QLabel(self)
        self.ScreenShot.setPixmap(QPixmap(self.screenshots[0]))
        self.ScreenShot.setGeometry(60, 60, 1280, 720)
        
        self.slider = QSlider(Qt.Horizontal, self)
        self.slider.setTickInterval(1)

        self.slider.setMinimum(min)
        self.slider.setMaximum(max)
        self.slider.setGeometry(100, 830, 1000, 20)
        self.slider.valueChanged[int].connect(self.changedValue)
        self.slider.setTickPosition(QSlider.TicksBelow)

        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon("icon.png"))
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.top, self.left, self.width, self.height)

        self.setLayout(hbox)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)
        self.show()

    def changedValue(self, value):
        # change value of the slider when you move the slider and switch to the next img
        start = time.process_time()

        image = QImage(self.screenshots[value])
        pixmap = QPixmap.fromImage(image)
        self.ScreenShot.setPixmap(QPixmap(pixmap))
        print(self.screenshots[value])

        val = self.slider.value()
        self.slider_text.setText(str(val))

        print('Time taken by changedValue:', time.process_time() - start)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    App = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    sys.exit(App.exec_())
```

The read_screenshot() function:

```
import os

def read_screenshots():
    screenshot_map = {}
    key = 0
    folder_dir = "./screenshots/"
    for images in os.listdir(folder_dir):
        # check if the image ends with png or jpg or jpeg
        key = key+1
        if (images.endswith(".png") or images.endswith(".jpg")\
            or images.endswith(".jpeg")):
            # display
            screenshot_map[key] = folder_dir + images
    print('Loaded Screenshots')
    return list(screenshot_map.keys())[0], list(screenshot_map.keys())[-1], list(screenshot_map.values())
```

The screenshot folder has over 60k images of size 350Kb and a resolution of 1280x720. As I move the slider the image takes a couple of seconds to load, is it possible to make it faster?

Comment: It's not [Py]Qt's fault. Loading images takes some time, depending on both the read speed from the disk *and* the cpu:, since the slider sends signals continuously when it's moved, the loading is then *queued* (since it's serial, not parallel). There's no easy solution for this, that's why developers take a lot of time to implement various strategies for both caching and preloading in image browsers: you have to decide what you want to do and how it should behave, and possibly implement the above tactics using QThreads.

Comment: You should consider disabling the [`tracking`](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractslider.html#tracking-prop), so that the signal is emitted only when the slider is released. Also, there's no need to do `QPixmap(pixmap)`, nor pass through QImage: just do `self.ScreenShot.setPixmap(QPixmap(self.screenshots[value]))`.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the behaviour. Using a uncached directory of 4.8 MiB (4608x3456) JPEG files, I get an average of about 0.15 secs per load. On subsequent passes (i.e. after os file-caching), the average drops to about 0.125 secs. This is on Linux using Qt-5.15.7. I suppose it's *possible* that your system is *200 hundred times* slower than mine, but I doubt it. Presumably, the script shown in your question is different from the one you're actually testing with, or there's some other crucial information you're not telling us about.

Comment: @musicamante what would my code look like if I disable tracking?